# TS2339: Property message does not exist on type {}

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, rtk-query

I am using React-Redux and Typescript and getting an error:

> TS2339: Property message does not exist on type {}

```js
import type { RootState } from "../store.ts";
import { fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query'
import type {
  BaseQueryFn,
  FetchArgs,
  FetchBaseQueryError,
} from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'
import { createApi } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";

const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3500/api/v1/',
    credentials: 'include',
    prepareHeaders: (headers: Headers, { getState }) => {
        const token: string|null = (getState() as RootState).auth.token
        if (token) {
            headers.set("authorization", `Bearer ${token}`)
        }
        return headers
    }
});

const baseQueryWithReauth: BaseQueryFn<
    string | FetchArgs,
    unknown,
    FetchBaseQueryError
> = async (args, api, extraOptions) => {
    const result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions)
    console.log(result?.data?.message.AT);
    return result
}
```

How can I get `result.data.message.AT` without getting error?

I am returning data from backend like this:

```js
res.status(200)
  .send({
    success: true,
    message: { AT: accessToken } }
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data` type is `any` in non-error responses, see [fetchBaseQuery](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/fetchBaseQuery#signature):

> ```
> type FetchBaseQueryResult = Promise<
>   | {
>       data: any
>       error?: undefined
>       meta?: { request: Request; response: Response }
>     }
>   | {
>       error: {
>         status: number
>         data: any
>       }
>       data?: undefined
>       meta?: { request: Request; response: Response }
>     }
> >
> ```

You can cast the response `data` property.

Example:

```js
type ResponseData = {
  success: boolean;
  message: {
    AT: string;
  };
}

...

const baseQueryWithReauth: BaseQueryFn<
  string | FetchArgs,
  unknown,
  FetchBaseQueryError
> = async (args, api, extraOptions) => {
  const result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions);

  if (result.data) {
    const data = result.data as ResponseData;
    console.log(data.message.AT);
  }

  return result;
}
```